# extra space being added in array output

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a custom function to take a array and add comma. Like for a location or list of items.

```
function arraylist($params)
{
    $paramlist = reset($params);
    while($item = next($params))
    {
        $paramlist = $item . ', ' . $paramlist;
    }
    return $paramlist;
}

$location = array('San Francisco','California','United States');

echo arraylist($location);
```

`San Francisco , California, United States` is the output. It should out put `San Francisco, California, United States`

Comment: i recommend reading the php documentation at http://www.php.net/ -- it's not always useful to reinvent the wheel ;-). "implode" is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of the function `implode` already present in PHP, is there a reason you do this by hand?

```
echo implode(', ', array('San Francisco','California','United States'));
```

The above does the same as your `arraylist`-function.

*Small update:* I noticed you append your 'next item' to the beginning of your string (`$item . ', ' . $paramlist`), which will inverse your array order. The output will be (`United States, California, San Francisco`). If this is on purpose, please use `array_reverse` to achieve the same ordering (together with `implode`).

Comment: I have `San Francisco , California, United States` being outputted using `implode(', ',array_reverse($location));` Still a space after the city name...

Comment: Your input and output does not match, because if you do this `echo implode(', ', array_reverse(array('San Francisco','California','United States')));` your output should be this `United States, California, San Francisco`, yours is the other way around. Please copy and paste $location **exactly**.

Comment: Opps. My Array is being genreated by php/mysql, but here is the print_r `Array ( [0] => United States [1] => California [2] => San Francisco )`

Comment: Then, most likely, your problem originates in the MySQL database, can you please execute this code: `echo var_dump($location[0]);`. It should report `string(13) "San Francisco"`, but my guess is that it will report `string(14) "San Francisco "`.

Comment: Oh. I found the problem. The place database has a space after cities names for some reason...

Comment: Oh. Didn't see your post before mine. Its a database issue.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to remove the space at the end only. some don't and some do have it.

Comment: No problem, glad it has been solved. Good luck finishing the project.

Comment: Yes there is, try to use the PHP built-in function `trim()`, which is made specially for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead just use `implode(", ", $location)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is already and existent function for doing this, called implode.

```
echo implode(',',$array);
```

that will covert the array into a string with a , in between , u can change ',' into any thing you want :)/

hope it helps